# jquery get textbox value if not null

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox for creating a user

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkCreateNewUser" name="chkCreateNewUser"/><label for="chkCreateNewUser">Create New User</label>
```

then i have this jquery

```
$("Input").click(function(){
    if($('#chkCreateNewUser').attr('checked')){
  $('#Firstname').val("");
}
```

when i type in the textbox and click the next textbox, the value i typed disappears. how do i make it when if the value of the textbox is not empty, the value typed stays?

I tried assigning it to avariable and displaying that variable but it just shows "[Object, Object]". I know theres a simple solution thanks

Comment: You want to only delete the value if the value doesn't exist?

Comment: we really need more code to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not disable the form when the element is unchecked. Just a suggestion.

```
$('#chkCreateNewUser').change(function(){
if($(this).attr('checked'))
  $('form#formId').find(':input').attr('disabled',true);
else
 $('form#formId').find(':input').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Alsom, make sure your checkbox is not inside that form, otherwise it will get disabled too

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're click event is on all inputs, so every input sees it and clears it.

Comment: if the user typed something into the textbox i want it to stay. right now when the user types and i click on the next textbox, what the user types diasappears

Comment: yes that's because   .val("") sets the value of the input to an empty string.  while  .val() will return what the value is.  Because you have .val("") in your code you are telling it to set the fields value to an empty string